# How do you calculate the measurements for an hourglass?

Tags: structural-engineering

I'm trying to build an hourglass, but I don't know what all the specs are that determine exactly how long it takes a given volume of what material to finish within a certain time. Are there any hourglass equations anywhere?

Comment: Think of continuity of mass , viscosity but without any info re fluid or dimensions ... Also look on the www for the pitchblend experiment (http://smp.uq.edu.au/content/pitch-drop-experiment)

Comment: Personally I'd recommend trial and error...

Comment: See [this question on Physics.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/8755/how-does-the-period-of-an-hourglass-depend-on-the-grain-size), especially the article linked in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can pretty much guarantee that the only way to calibrate an hourglass is to build it,  fill it with your choice of particles (preferably non-hygroscopic!) and time it.  Add or remove material until you get the timing desired.

Granted, a mass-production line only needs to do this once and then reproduce the glass figure to tight tolerance, but you aren't going that way.

Comment: I mean this isn't magic, it's classical mechanics, it's based on friction of the sane with the sand, sand with the glass, and the change in radius of the shape. It's okay that you don't know the answer, no one's forcing you to say anything.

Comment: @RayOfHope no, it isn't magic, but your naive assumptions about the accuracy and predictive capability of engineering formulas will lead you to ruin.

Comment: It's not really an assumption, it's already determined by our inherent knowledge of mechanics that it's more than possible to predict it for the macroscopic world. The only thing I'm looking for is if someone publicly released the formula or if it's still a trade secret. At worst you can use fluid dynamics formulas and there's plenty of those. If people can predict fluid, they can sure as hell predict inanimate sand. The only thing that makes this different than calculating exactly where an object falls off a building is the number of variables.

Comment: @RayofHope if you can "predict" the friction coefficient of *anything* with an accuracy better than $-50\%$ $+100\%$, you just got very lucky. That's the difference between the real world and some nice simple equations in a high-school textbook on statics. Even with liquid like water, the viscosity can change by $30\%$ for a $10$ degree temperature change, so your "prediction" wouldn't be accurate for most of the time.

Comment: I'm not asking to predict the coefficient of friction so your point is moot, but even still, it is absolutely predictable to a degree that it is usable on the macroscopic level which there's plenty of research papers on, it is only that it requires a lot of variables which is why computer simulations are better for predicting it spontaneously. I also see no reason why you would assume conditions are changing so rapidly if something were factory produced.